# Movie from 80's-90's where space station (humans and aliens friendly) has some kind of air ventilation malfunction

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

So it is my first post and I don't have much to go on.

It is a movie from my childhood (I was born in 88). I assume it was from the 80's or 90's (Color film).

I remember it being a sci-fi with some light humor, where a space station is shared by aliens and humans (almost sure it was on a planet). It has some kind of malfunction (I think it was with the air ventilation system) and I recall there was some kind of breach in parts of the station, so the oxygen was lost in those sections.

I remember one scene where they were in a waiting area. And also red/amber tones in the film.

The movie is a little eccentric and doesn't take itself too seriously.

I recall a female character as one of the main roles in the movie, accompanied by another person. Not sure if one of them was an alien. They were escaping/hiding from somebody.

Space station was big. Seemed to be more like a planet station with big rooms and lots of people/aliens (hundreds or more).

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Thanks. Added some more details. If I remember anything else, I will definitely update!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like it might be [Total Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_(1990_film)) (the 1990 Schwarzenegger version, not the more recent remake)

> I remember it being a sci-fi with some light humor, where a space station is shared by aliens and humans

There's no aliens shown, but there are mutated people

> almost sure it was on a planet

Most of the movie takes place on Mars. There's no space station, but the colony kinda acts like one (tight corridors, some areas with windows looking out on Mars)

> It has some kind of malfunction (I think it was with the air ventilation system)

The antagonist (who is wealthy due to selling air to the colony) has the air shut off to the part where most of the mutated humans live

> I recall there was some kind of breach in parts of the station, so the oxygen was lost in those sections.

There was an explosive decompression towards the end

> I remember one scene where they were in a waiting area. And also red/amber tones in the film.

Probably one of the more strange (if not iconic) scenes in the movie. Quaid, the central character, wears a talking mask while trying to pass through Mars customs. The redness of Mars is visible in all the windows

> I recall a female character as one of the main roles in the movie, accompanied by another person.

Quaid is accompanied for most of the movie by a woman named Melina ([Rachel Ticotin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Ticotin))

Comment: Thanks! From your answer it really does seem like it could be Total Recall! 


I'm watching a couple trailers and it seems like it could be the one. I must have watched it when I was veeeery young because some of the scenes look familiar and that's about it!